# Object stabilization in the real time video

Tags: computer-vision, video-processing, object-detection

I'm trying to make an shaking object look stabilized in a real time video.

For example if I am filming a video and streaming it live real time,
some object moves w.r.t some trajectory and vibrating at the same time( **true trajectory + noise** like fashion). So its something like a ball thrown following a parabolic trajectory and there is a mechanical vibrating device inside the ball. Vibration is about 10 Hz.

Video camera catches all the vibrations but looks blurry for human eye. 
I want to synthesize a video real time to get rid of the vibration so that the object looks stabilized, leaving only the **true trajectory**.

I thought about detecting the object and undersampling the region around the object but there should be something smarter then that.

Is there some keyword or concepts in computer vision or video synthesis area that I could take a look at?

Answer (score 0):

Well 'object tracking' is related;
You could track the object then only display the frames that have the object closest to its predicted average path. But if you provide details on why you want this done there might be a more practical approach. You can avoid predicting the path and just use an average if you are willing to introduce a little bit more lag on the live video.

Comment: I am real time monitoring some moving mechanical system with vibrating engine. The video of system looks blurry because it vibrates so much. Maybe I should just consider displaying the frames close to average like you said, but I want to know If there is a way to make the object move smoother.

Comment: One accomplishes the other (assuming you have a high enough frame rate to start with) (and assuming you are not talking about sharpening like if it's blury in a single frame)